# Dynamic Layout ( Different Layout for each Page )

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to implement different layouts in Joomla. I'm using the Alias Name for setting 
different layouts for each page. I read an E-book about Joomla and there's no another method to create different layouts and or set it in the Backend Panel.
I wanted to ask, is there be another method / way to set a different page from Backend Panel for each page ? I just want to make sure it's possible in Joomla 1.5.

**My Previous Method**

```
// Get Alias Page
function getCurrentAlias(){
   $menu= &JSite::getMenu();
   $active= $menu->getActive();
   return $active->alias;
}
```

After getting the Alias page name, I used a conditional statement to get different content 
for each page.

```
<-- Header Part -->
<-- Start Content Part -->
if( $pageName == "home" ){
   {{Content Home}}
}elseif( preg_match("#^(news).*$#", $pageName) ){
   {{Content News}}
}...etc
<-- End Content Part -->
<-- Footer Part -->
```

Comment: You're not clear: `method to set different page from Backend Panel for each page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wold recommend not using 1.5, it reaches end of life next month.

however, if you are going to use 1.5, you are making it a lot harder than you need to. If you want to have significant structural differences from one page to another, you can install a template for each different structure you would like to use, then assign each template to the appropriate menu item. You would have to create menu items, even if they are in a hidden menu that is not displayed on the site.

You can also control the structure of the page using CSS and collapsible module positions. Add this so you can set a page class suffix that adds an ID to the body tag of the page, making it easy to have page specific CSS:

```
<?php
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
if (is_object( $active )) :
$params = new JParameter( $active->params );
$pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );
endif;
?>

<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

Then for each of the module positions on the page, you can make them collapsible so they do not show up on the page if they are not being used:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('top')) : ?><div id="top"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="xhtml" /></div><?php endif; ?>
```

So basically, if you don't put any modules in the "top" position it never gets put on the page. Using these 2 items in combination you can control exactly how each page looks with a single template.

Comment: thanks, it works. Visibility of Module can be set in Admin Panel, but I have to use conditional statement too for supporting different structure.

Answer (score 0):

When we where using Joomla! 1.5 we used an extension called "[Menu Dependent Items](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/5465)" to load particular CSS, JS etc

Through loading the right CSS etc we where able to completely relayout any given page.

Of course with the advent of template "Styles" in Joomla! 2.5+ we no longer need it as we can assign just the style variation to the menu item.

Comment: It's not just load CSS or JS but different HTML layout, could it be possible in Joomla version 1.5